# Getting tie always with Rock Paper Scissors game Javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
const getUserChoice = (userInput) => {
  userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
  if (userInput === 'rock' || userInput === 'paper' || userInput === 'scissors') {
    return userInput
  } else {
    console.log('Error!')
  }
}

const getcomputerChoice = () => {
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
  switch (randomNumber) {
    case 0:
      return 'rock';
    case 1:
      return 'paper';
    case 2:
      return 'scissors';
  }
}



const determineWinner = (userChoice, computerChoice) => {
  if (userChoice === computerChoice) {
    return 'Tie'
  }
  if (userChoice === 'rock') {
    if (computerChoice === 'paper') {
      return 'computer won'
    } else {
      return 'user won'
    }
  }
  if (userChoice === 'paper') {
    if (computerChoice === 'scissors') {
      return 'computer won'
    } else {
      return 'user won'
    }
  }
  if (userChoice === 'scissors') {
    if (computerChoice === 'rock') {
      return 'computer won'
    } else {
      return 'user won'
    }
  }
}

const playGame = () => {
  var userChoice = getUserChoice()
  console.log(userChoice)
  var computerChoice = getcomputerChoice()
  console.log(computerChoice)
  console.log(determineWinner(userChoice, computerChoice))
}

console.log(determineWinner())
```

So I wanted to do a project with JS, was following codeacadem's course on the subject. But for some reason I am always getting a tie which I do not understand why. Can anyone please help me? I thought this is the correct code and every single object was working properly.

**UPDATE:**

After giving a parameter to the `userchoice` (`getUserChoice('scissors')`) I got this error: `userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();`

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')
```

Initializing playgame didnt solve the issue

Comment: `console.log(determineWinner())` should probably be `console.log(playGame())`

Comment: getUserChoice expects a parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've corrected your code with a few things:

- As *@James* has commented, `getUserChoice()` expects a parameter for the choice of the user but none is given at `playGame()`.
- As *@Alon Eitan* has commented, `console.log(determineWinner())` doesn't play the game at all as it just calls `determineWinner()` with the two parameters undefined. And actually that's why **Tie** is always returned as `undefined == undefined`.

```js
const getUserChoice = (userInput) => {
  userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
  if (userInput === 'rock' || userInput === 'paper' || userInput === 'scissors') {
    return userInput
  } else {
    console.log('Error!')
  }
}



const getcomputerChoice = () => {
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
  switch (randomNumber) {
    case 0:
      return 'rock';
    case 1:
      return 'paper';
    case 2:
      return 'scissors';
  }
}



const determineWinner = (userChoice, computerChoice) => {
  if (userChoice === computerChoice) {
    return 'Tie'
  }
  if (userChoice === 'rock') {
    if (computerChoice === 'paper') {
      return 'computer won'
    } else {
      return 'user won'
    }
  }
  if (userChoice === 'paper') {
    if (computerChoice === 'scissors') {
      return 'computer won'
    } else {
      return 'user won'
    }
  }
  if (userChoice === 'scissors') {
    if (computerChoice === 'rock') {
      return 'computer won'
    } else {
      return 'user won'
    }
  }
}

const playGame = () => {
  var userChoice = getUserChoice("rock")
  console.log(userChoice)
  var computerChoice = getcomputerChoice()
  console.log(computerChoice)
  console.log(determineWinner(userChoice, computerChoice))
}

playGame()
```